# how to display a layout dynamically with margin

Tags: android

I have two layouts, i inflate one layout into another and want to display this inflated layout including textview as many times as condition is true . I set the textview value as value of i and also set the layout top margin. but it displaying value of i in one row only and rest are blank,also its setMargin() also not working.Below is what i have done yet.

```
public void displayRows(){
            int n= 6;
           for(int i=0;i< n;i++){

            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutContainer);

            View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dynamic, container, false);
            container.addView(hiddenInfo);
            LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamic);

           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

          textView.setText("Text"+i);

          LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

         layoutParams.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
          hiddenLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
          hiddenLayout.addView(textView);
                }
```

container.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="displayRows"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Rows"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

dynamic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also want to know how to remove all the generated dynamic rows on click remove button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

with

```
LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
TextView textView = (TextView) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

And remove this line

```
hiddenLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: its giving me IllegalStateException that The specified child already has a parent.

Comment: thanks alot its working. please also let me know how to remove all these generated rows on remove button click.

Comment: `container.removeAllViews()` - to remove all subviews. Please accept the answer.